# Why can't I delete files I created in code in Metro style apps?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, io, microsoft-metro

I can create, read from and edit files created by my application in my Metro style app, but it won't let me delete (and yes, I do have the necessary Declarations and File type associations set) them!

I get `Access is denied.` message, for the same code that is used (and works) in the Windows 8 Metro File Acccess sample:

```
private async void RemoveNote_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        StorageFile file = await KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.GetFileAsync(NotesList.SelectedItem.ToString());
        if (file != null)
        {
            await file.DeleteAsync();
            file = null;
        }

        notes.RemoveAt(NotesList.Items.IndexOf(NotesList.SelectedItem));
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        throw new Exception(exception.Message);
    }
}
```

Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget to close a file stream somewhere?

Comment: :-/ Nope, @spender - I actually remembered to close them. Since there's no Dispose() or Close() for StorageFile, I assign it a null value like `file = null;` - as seen in the Metro samples. Is that enough?

Comment: @JTS-V do you use a DataWriter or StorageStreamTransaction? Those need to be wrapped in a `using` block

Comment: I just realised, that when I get the `SelectedItem` - it doesn't get the value of the selected item. It simply returns `NoteView.Note` - so that's why it says Access is denied. But, then, how do I get the Text value of the Selected Item in a XAML Metro ListBox?